# How to get keystroke sequence in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume I have such code:

```
function onKeystroke(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 39)  //Arrow Right
    {
        currentCell += 1;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37)  //Arrow Left
    {
        currentCell -= 1;
    }       

    if (e.keyCode>47 && e.keyCode<58)  //Numbers 0-9
    {
        cells[currentCell] = e.keyCode - 48;
    }             
}
```

But I need not only to get a single number but also two digit numbers. The program should behave like this:
- if the user moves into an empty cell and presses the "2" key, number "2" appears in the cell. If he now presses "3", number becomes "23". Next keypress (let's say "7") starts it over and puts alove "7" in the cell.
- if the user moves into a cell where "2" is already written and then presses "3", only the "3" appears and the subsequent stroke of "7" makes it "37".

So moving out of a cell should "close" it similar to what happens in MS Excel.

I know that I can track a cell being in open or closed state, but that would require to attach the cell "closing" to all of the movement functions. And that's a bit problem, because I have far more than two of those in my actual program. It's not impossible, but I'd like to know if there is some nicer approach so I could get the expected behaviour by just writing the right script for the if (e.keyCode>47 && e.keyCode<58) case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic way to track the application state without writing some code that tracks it =P. You will have to update you movement functions to track if the cell just got focused. However, if your cells are focusable and have a `tabindex`, you could use the `focus` event to centralize this logic. Without using the 'focus' event, your current function could look like:

```
var isNewCell = false;

function onKeystroke(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 39)  //Arrow Right
    {
        currentCell += 1;
        isNewCell = true;

    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37)  //Arrow Left
    {
        currentCell -= 1;
        isNewCell = true;
    }       

    if (e.keyCode>47 && e.keyCode<58)  //Numbers 0-9
    {
        if (isNewCell || typeof cells[currentCell] !== 'number' || cells[currentCell].toString().length === 2) {
            cells[currentCell] = e.keyCode - 48;
        } else {
            cells[currentCell] = parseInt(cells[currentCell] + (e.keyCode - 48).toString(), 10);
        }

        isNewCell = false;
    }             
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! But can I smoehow avoid editing all the movement functions?

Comment: What do you mean "all the movement functions"? You just have to reuse the same `onKeystroke` function.

Comment: I mean the "sub-functions" or just "parts" in "if (e.keyCode == some movement)" cases